# JavaScript Code behind seleniums "clickAt()" method?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to do exactly that what seleniums "clickAt()" Method is doing. It is different from seleniums and the normal javascript command "click()".

Because "clickAt" is working for ajax testing when the normal "click"-method is not.

Let's Say I want to do a clickAt, at the element with the ID: myid

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
/* Fire a mouse event in a browser-compatible manner */

BrowserBot.prototype.triggerMouseEvent = function(element, eventType, canBubble, clientX, clientY, button) {
    clientX = clientX ? clientX : 0;
    clientY = clientY ? clientY : 0;

    LOG.debug("triggerMouseEvent assumes setting screenX and screenY to 0 is ok");
    var screenX = 0;
    var screenY = 0;

    canBubble = (typeof(canBubble) == undefined) ? true : canBubble;
    var evt;
    if (element.fireEvent && element.ownerDocument && element.ownerDocument.createEventObject) { //IE
        evt = createEventObject(element, this.controlKeyDown, this.altKeyDown, this.shiftKeyDown, this.metaKeyDown);
        evt.detail = 0;
        evt.button = button ? button : 1; // default will be the left mouse click ( http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml )
        evt.relatedTarget = null;
        if (!screenX && !screenY && !clientX && !clientY && !this.controlKeyDown && !this.altKeyDown && !this.shiftKeyDown && !this.metaKeyDown) {
            element.fireEvent('on' + eventType);
        }
        else {
            evt.screenX = screenX;
            evt.screenY = screenY;
            evt.clientX = clientX;
            evt.clientY = clientY;

            // when we go this route, window.event is never set to contain the event we have just created.
            // ideally we could just slide it in as follows in the try-block below, but this normally
            // doesn't work.  This is why I try to avoid this code path, which is only required if we need to
            // set attributes on the event (e.g., clientX).
            try {
                window.event = evt;
            }
            catch(e) {
                // getting an "Object does not support this action or property" error.  Save the event away
                // for future reference.
                // TODO: is there a way to update window.event?

                // work around for http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-280 -- make the event available somewhere:
                selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().selenium_event = evt;
            }
            element.fireEvent('on' + eventType, evt);
        }
    }
    else {
        evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        if (evt.initMouseEvent)
        {
            // see http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:event.button and
            // http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:event.initMouseEvent for button ternary logic logic
            //Safari
            evt.initMouseEvent(eventType, canBubble, true, document.defaultView, 1, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY,
                this.controlKeyDown, this.altKeyDown, this.shiftKeyDown, this.metaKeyDown, button ? button : 0, null);
        }
        else {
            LOG.warn("element doesn't have initMouseEvent; firing an event which should -- but doesn't -- have other mouse-event related attributes here, as well as controlKeyDown, altKeyDown, shiftKeyDown, metaKeyDown");
            evt.initEvent(eventType, canBubble, true);

            evt.shiftKey = this.shiftKeyDown;
            evt.metaKey = this.metaKeyDown;
            evt.altKey = this.altKeyDown;
            evt.ctrlKey = this.controlKeyDown;
            if(button)
            {
              evt.button = button;
            }
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
};
```

This came from the Selenium source code which is available at:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js